# Jquery change dropdown based on clicked link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the selected value in a dropdown based upon which link a user clicks on

```
<a id="1" href="#1">number 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#2">number 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#3">number 3</a>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="option one">option one</option>
    <option value="option two">option two</option>
    <option value="option three">option three</option>
</select>
```

When I user clicks the number 2 link, I would like the dropdown to display option two. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried using .prop and .val within a .click function, but haven't had any luck

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-option` attribute to your links. Value of this attribute should correspond to value of the `option` you want to be selected:

```
<a id="1" href="#1" data-option="option one">number 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#2" data-option="option two">number 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#3" data-option="option three">number 3</a>
```

Attach `click` listener to your links. Inside it get the `data-option` value of clicked link and, using it, find the `option` you want to select:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e){
    //get clicked value
    var option = $(this).attr("data-option");

    //find the option to select
    var optionToSelect = $("#dropdown").children("[value='" + option + "']");

    //mark the option as selected
    optionToSelect.prop("selected", "selected");
    return false;
});
```

## Demo is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/LA98P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just selected the option by targeting the index value. It's a lot neater and minimal code

```
$('a').on('click', function(){    
    var id = this.id;
    $('#dropdown')[0].selectedIndex = id - 1;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/nGfSY/)**

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){    

    var id = this.id;

   switch(n) {

       case '1':
           $('#dropdown').selectedIndex = 0;
       break;

       case '2':
           $('#dropdown').selectedIndex = 1;    
       break;

       case '3':
           $('#dropdown').selectedIndex = 2; 
       break;

    }

});
```